# Why are ultrasound devices using ultrasound?

Tags: acoustics, electrical-engineering

I wonder why ultrasound devices are using ultrasound. Is it a biological reason due to our human audible range? Or is there a physical reason for that?

The question mainly aims at understanding why ultrasound is used in medical applications, why not other frequencies e.g. lower or even higher?

Comment: What ultrasonic devices do you have in mind? Ultrasonic cleaning baths? Ultrasonic scanners? Different devices will use ultrasound for different reasons.

Comment: While we're at it, you could just as easily ask why subsonic devices exist.  You need to specify exactly what application or situation you're interested in, at which point we can discuss things like penetration depths, phase-shift resolution, etc.

Comment: It was a general question but I'm mainly only aware of (medical) ultrasound scanners and cleaning baths..   in general because what distinguishes ultrasound from "regular" sound is only the frequency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll pick up the specific topic of ultrasonic cleaning baths and explain why high frequency sound is used for those.

If we have a sound wave passing through water and we watch some particular bit of water we find the water oscillates about its average position with the position being given by:

$$ x(t) = A \sin(\omega t) \tag{1} $$

Here $A$ is the maximum amplitude of the oscillation and $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the oscillation, which is related to the sound frequency $f$ by $\omega = 2 \pi f$. We get the velocity that the bit of water moves by differentiating equation (1):

$$ v(t) = A \omega \cos(\omega t) \tag{2} $$

and we get the acceleration with which the water moves by differentiating again:

$$ a(t) = - A \omega^2 \sin(\omega t) \tag{3} $$

Note that in equation (3) the acceleration is proportional to $\omega^2$ so that means if we keep the amplitude $A$ the acceleration of the water increases as the square of the frequency. In an ultrasonic cleaner it's this acceleration that literally tears the water apart and creates a cavity, and the collapse of these cavities is [how an ultrasonic cleaner cleans surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasonic_cleaning#Process_characteristics). The reason we use high frequencies is because the acceleration is proportional to $f^2$ so increasing the frequency gives us higher accelerations and more cavitation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I believed as a physical reason :) Can you also add something for ultrasonic scanning? I guess it mus be quite a different reason there :D
But with this explanation I even wonder know if we clean ourselves everytime we get scanned..

Answer (score 3):

Ultrasound is fairly good at penetrating and differentiating soft tissues so analysing ultrasound echoes in an ultrasound scan can produce real-time images of structures inside the body without the harmful side effects of ionising radiation such as x-rays. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_ultrasound#Attributes) lists some of the strengths and weaknesses of ultrasound scanning.

Comment: With a shorter wavelength, ultra sound can give an image with higher resolution.

Comment: @R.W.Bird  "higher resolution.."  than what?  :-) .  Increase the frequency of any kind of energy beam and you can get better distance resolution.

Comment: Higher than audible sound.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the most basic answer with regards to why we use ultrasound for *imaging* rather than sound in the human range of hearing.  Ultrasound, by nature, is high frequency.  The higher the frequency, the denser the sound traveling through the medium, which, in turn, provides a higher resolution image.  You could certainly create an image using sound waves less than 20 KHz (lower limit of ultrasound),  however, the information contained in the reflected signal would be too crude to be of use.  Think of ultrasound as taking a photo with a modern several megapixel camera.  High resolution.  Using sound in the range of human hearing for imaging would be comparable to using a camera that only displays a handful of pixels across the image.

Comment: thank you, is there some kind of mathematical expression that shows the resolution or the like in dependency on the frequency?